# android Sliding tabs error

Tags: android

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html?showComment=1436589272036#c4263987424044722040) for making a sliding tab for my application and after that I have encountered error:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cap2.macsanity.droidgency/com.cap2.macsanity.droidgency.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class

this is my activity main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <com.cap2.macsanity.droidgency.
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any one can help me? thanks in advance.

EDIT 2#
It's fixed and solve now thanks.

Comment: Can you post your xml here?

Comment: sir/mam nilaydani i editted my post already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, just define your proper library name with the desired package name with class and if you press CTRL + Click, than it will be redirected to your class, and if it's not than your library name with the class name does not exists.

if your library name is com.cap2.macsanity.droidgency. and your package name Activity and your class name is MainActivity, than your selected line would be

```
<com.cap2.macsanity.droidgency.Activity.MainActivity
!-------
!------
/>
```

I hope this will work for you. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <com.cap2.macsanity.droidgency.
```

> Here is the issue correct this with proper class name

Comment: another error sir @NilayDani "    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cap2.macsanity.droidgency/com.cap2.macsanity.droidgency.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead"